# Trouble Unpacking Dictionary of Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I am having a devil of a time trying to work with Dictionaries in Swift.  I have created the following Dictionary of Dictionaries but I am unable to unpack it.

```
var holeDictionary = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int>>>()
```

I can get the first Dictionary out with:

```
var aDictionary = holeDictionary["1"]
```

But trying to access the next Dictionary within it gives me an error as follows:

```
var bDictionary = aDictionary["key"]  // [String : Dictionary<String, Int>]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

I know what the contents of the Dictionaries are and can verify them with a println(aDictionary).  So how can I get to the Dictionaries buried deeper down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key subscript on `Dictionary` returns an optional, because the key-value pair may or may not exist in the dictionary.

You need to use an if-let binding or force unwrap the optional before you can access it to subscript it further:

```
if let aDictionary = holeDictionary["1"] {
    let bDictionary = aDictionary["key"]
}
```

Edit, to add forced unwrap example:

If you're sure that the key `"1"` exists, and you're okay with `assert()`ing at runtime if the key doesn't exist, you can force-unwrap the optional like this:

```
let bDictionary = holeDictionary["1"]!["key"]
```

And if you're sure that the key `"key"` will exist, you'd do this instead:

```
let bDictionary = holeDictionary["1"]!["key"]!
```

Comment: I understand that I need to use the if let in order to be sure there is a value for the key but do I then need to use as? Dictionary as well?

Comment: No, because the compiler knows that `holeDictionary` values are of type `Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int>>`.

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to the swift documentation:

```
Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, 
a dictionary’s subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary’s 
value type
```

When you retrieve an item from a dictionary you have an optional value returned. The correct way to handle your case is:

```
var holeDictionary = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int>>>()
if let aDictionary = holeDictionary["1"] {
    var bDictionary = aDictionary["key"]
}
```